# Getting minimum time difference

Tags: java

I was asked this question recently in a coding interview. I'm given a series of times in HH:MM format. I need to find the minimum time difference in minutes. The time is circular in nature, thus 23:55 and 00:12 should have a difference of 17. The function also needs to handle 00:00 as the same thing as 24:00(this is the easiest part, naturally).
Can someone help me get started with the problem.

Comment: Can I ask how much time you were given for this question?

Comment: Does the second time always occur after the first?

Comment: @bphilipnyc 45 minutes white boarding.

Comment: @Zeus , **SpiderPig** provides a very good descriptive answer. you could try my answer as sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like bellow:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String times[] = {"2:30","00:00", "00:12", "24:00", "23:55"};/*input times*/
        int countTime = times.length;
        int sortedTimes[] = new int[countTime];/*will hold sorted times*/

        for (int i = 0; i < countTime; i++) {/*convert 'HH:mm' to integer minute*/
            int t = Integer.valueOf(times[i].split(":")[0])*60 
                    + Integer.valueOf(times[i].split(":")[1]);
            sortedTimes[i] = t;
        }
        Arrays.sort(sortedTimes);/*sort times*/         
        /*variables to hold the result*/
        int minDiff = 1440;
        int minT1 = 1440;
        int minT2 = 1440;

        for (int i = 0; i < countTime; i++) {
            int curr = sortedTimes[i];
            int prev = sortedTimes[(countTime+i-1)%countTime];
            int diffPrev = Math.abs(curr - prev) < 1440 - Math.abs(curr - prev ) ? 
                    Math.abs(curr - prev) :  1440 - Math.abs(curr - prev  ) ; 
            if (minDiff > diffPrev) {
                    minDiff = diffPrev;
                    minT1 = prev;
                    minT2 = curr;                   
            }
        }       
        System.out.println("Minimum diff in minute: " + minDiff 
                + " between " + (minT1/60 + ":" + minT1%60) 
                + " and " + (minT2/60 + ":" + minT2%60));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First convert all times into minutes (HH * 60 + MM). Then sort that list of numbers. Now you can just go through that list and subtract each time from the following one. At the end of that loop you have to subtract the last from the first+1440.

Answer (score 0):

First convert both time into minutes.Subtract larger time and smaller time to get first difference.Then add 24 hour i.e 1440 minutes to the smaller time and again subtract time.Which ever difference is less is the correct answer.Two difference are required for forward and backward differences.

Comment: This is what I thought of too, but I think the computational complexity of this is very high. Each number must be compared to every other number, so I think that's `O(n!)`, or equivalent to solving the traveling salesman problem via brute-force search ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities)). SpiderPig's solution sorts the numbers first to avoid this: there is no need to compare times that aren't adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Solution here:

```js
var findMinDifference = function(timePoints) {
  let min = Infinity;

  let data = timePoints.map(d => timeToMin(d));

  //sorting data
  let sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  for (let i = 1; i < sortedData.length; i++) {
    min = Math.min(min, sortedData[i] - sortedData[i - 1]);
  }

  //subtract the last from the first 1440.
  let firstLastDiff =
    60 * 24 - (sortedData[sortedData.length - 1] - sortedData[0]);

 
  min = Math.min(firstLastDiff, min);

  return min;
};

// convert all times into minutes (HH * 60 + MM)
function timeToMin(t) {
  const [hours, min] = t.split(":").map(d => parseInt(d));
  return hours * 60 + min;
}
```

Comment: The Question asks for Java, not JavaScript.