# Array - Time difference in minutes

Tags: java

I have four different timestamps where I have to find the smallest difference in minutes. I'm confused on how to do this.

Example:
String array: ["2:10pm", "1:30pm", "10:30am", "4.42pm"]

How can I find the smallest difference in minutes. Do I use LocalDate?

Comment: You could convert the hours into minutes and then build the differences of all and check witch is the lowerst

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532322/getting-minimum-time-difference) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
This will help you to get smallest in minutes from array 

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] myarr =  {"2:10pm", "1:20pm", "10:30am", "4:42pm"};
        int index = 0;
        int smallest = Integer.parseInt(myarr[0].substring(myarr[0].lastIndexOf(":") + 1,myarr[0].lastIndexOf(":") + 3));
        
        for (int i = 1; i  < myarr.length; i++){
        int myValue = Integer.parseInt(myarr[i].substring(myarr[i].lastIndexOf(":") + 1,myarr[i].lastIndexOf(":") + 3));
            
            if (myValue < smallest){
            smallest = myValue;
            index = i;
            }
        }
        
        
        System.out.println(myarr[index] + " is smallest in minutes");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to get the minimum difference between those timestamps!